# How to make pandas#read_csv raise exception when some columns missed

Tags: python, pandas

As following, the last line of `text` has a missed column. I want `read_csv` raise an exception rather than return a `DataFrame` with `NaN` value. Is this possible?

A row with missed column if  `len(row.split(sep)) < len(columns)`.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from io import StringIO

In [3]: text = """x,y,z
   ...: 1,2,3
   ...: 4,5,6
   ...: 7,8"""

In [4]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   x  y   z
0  1  2   3
1  4  5   6
2  7  8 NaN
```

Comment: @Merlin A row with missed column if  `len(row.split(sep)) < len(columns)`.

Comment: Its missing data,not entire column.   The best solution is csvreader then.. it could force line counts.

Comment: Hacky way: `pd.read_csv(..., na_filter=False, dtype=float)` raises. `dtype` can be a dict of types. But it won't work with string columns.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like there's an easy way to get the `read_csv` function to do what you're asking, according to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

However, you can use `df.isnull().values.any()`. That statement will evaluate to `True` if there exists a `NaN` in `df`, and `False` otherwise, which should accomplish your task. So, immediately after you read in your csv you could write:

```
if df.isnull().values.any():
    raise ValueError("Found a NaN")
```

HTH.